# How to create custom header-right element

Tags: react-native, clojurescript

I have a button

```
(defn create-task-button []
  [rnu/button {:title    "+"
               :on-press #(rf/dispatch [:navigate-to :create-task])}])
```

I wanna add this button in header, like this: [Header buttons](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons)

I trying to do this

```
(defn app-component []
  [(rnn/create-navigation-container-reload
    [stack/stack
     [{:name      :home
       :component home-comp
       :options   {:title        "Home"
                   :header-right (fn [] create-task-button)}}
      {:name      :create-task
       :component create-task-comp
       :options   {:title "Create Task"}}]])])
```

And then I have a warning:

```
Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render
```

What am I doing wrong? :-)

Comment: `:header-right (fn [] create-task-button)` - I assume it should be `:header-right (r/as-element [create-task-button])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
:header-right (fn [] (r/as-element [create-task-button]))
```

TY [Eugene Pakhomov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564509/eugene-pakhomov)